# Constant Throughput timer not fetching throughput value from preprocessor properly

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where a log with millions of samples has different rps rate.
eg: 1 sec may have 1000 samples and next sec samples are reduced to 400 and so on

So I used Constant throughput timer to fetch different rps values from script and proceed accordingly.

Implemented below in PreProcessor:

```
props.put("throughput", num_of_reqs);
```

Where num_of_reqs i.e rps is calculated from log.
As per my test log rps values are [5, 10, 5, 20]

Configured timer as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3kei.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPTWg.png)

I am expecting transactions per sec to be 5, 10, 5 and 20 but actual result is below 5 every time:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zswwh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djez3.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) can only **pause** JMeter threads in order to **limit** JMeter's throughput to the desired value. So you need to supply the sufficient amount of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group).

Second, it works precise enough on "minute" level. As per documentation:

> Note that the throughput value should not be changed too often during a test - it will take a while for the new value to take effect.

Try out [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin), it gives you more flexibility when it comes to defining the number of requests per second:

[image]

The load pattern can be defined using [`tst-name.load_profile` property](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) if you need to "calculate" the load profile using external data source.

Comment: Initially I tried with Throughput shaping timer, since I have different rps rate I need to keep on dynamically change startRPS and endRPS and couldnt find a way to do that. Is there a way to dynamically change startRPS and endRPS multiple times based on load

Comment: If you want to do it in the runtime you can use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(startRPS,1)}` or `${__P(endRPS,1)}` and then set the properties values from i.e. [JSR223 Test Elements](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) like `props.put('startRPS', '25')` where required.